# After my if statement nothing happened. Else is being ignored

Tags: android, firebase, for-loop, if-statement, size

What its supposed to do is after getting `ProgramTracker` size it checks if there is still an unfinished exercise inside `ProgramTracker` and if it detects an unfinished exercise it changes the `falseDetected` which is `false` to `true` and then goes to my else statement which it should show my `viewKonfetti`.

```
private void checkIfCurrentWeekProgramComplete() {

    currentWeek = programTrackers.get(0).getWeek();

    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ProgramTracker")
            .child(GlobalUser.getmUser().getiD())
            .child(programTrackers.get(0).getProgramId());

    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ProgramTracker programTracker = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProgramTracker.class);
            if (programTracker.getProgramExerciseWeek() == currentWeek) {
                programTrackers.add(programTracker);
                if (programTrackers.size() == programTrackers.size()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < programTrackers.size(); i++) {
                        if (!programTrackers.get(i).isProgramExerciseFinished()) {
                            falseDetected = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (falseDetected) {
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        //meaning this week for the current program is done
                        viewKonfetti = findViewById(R.id.viewKonfetti);
                        viewKonfetti.build()
                                .addColors(Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA)
                                .setDirection(0.0, 359.0)
                                .setDirection(0.0, 359.0)
                                .setSpeed(1f, 5f)
                                .setFadeOutEnabled(true)
                                .setTimeToLive(2000L)
                                .addShapes(Shape.RECT, Shape.CIRCLE)
                                .addSizes(new Size(12, 5))
                                .setPosition(-50f, viewKonfetti.getWidth() + 50f, -50f, -50f)
                                .streamFor(300, 5000L);

                        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                        InputWeightDialog weightDialog = new InputWeightDialog();
                        weightDialog.show(fm, "fragment_input_weight");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the concept of if else. Of course, your else block will be ignored once you if block is executed. It is either if block or else block. Also, you are calling finish() in your if block which would close the current activity

Comment: In my activity, what it does is execute some exercises and after that, the falseDetected which is false will now be true. I'm calling finish() in my if block since every time the user finishes executing the exercise, the user will be directed out of that activity. All that is doing great but my problem is after executing everything and falseDetected is equal to true my else block is being ignored.

Comment: also in my firebase isProgramFinished is already true.

Comment: If you want to execute your else block when falseDetected is true move your else block code inside your if block above your finish() statement

Comment: I want my else block to be executed after all exercises are being done. If I move my else block inside the if block above the finish() statement, what will happen is that the else block will be executed every after an exercise is executed.

Comment: So you want your else block to be executed after the loop.Is that right? In that case instead, write your code inside else block outside the loop. I still not getting why are you using finish() inside the if block?

Comment: Yeah. If I remove the finish() statement, after executing the exercise I will still be at the same activity. Using the finish() statement, after executing the exercise I will be directed to the screen before the part where I'm executing the exercise. That is the difference.

Comment: Then put your finish() outside the loop after the code inside else block